# Route all requests to HomeController and Index action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I route all requests to my `HomeController`and my `Index` Action?

So for example if a requested URL looks like this:

`http://localhost/News/Tech/23`

Then I'd like to "capture" that in my `Index` action:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index (string uri)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

So in this case the string `url` should contain: "News/Tech/23".

But I have no idea how to configure the route for this. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define route and as the route template provide the following

```
"{*uri}"
```

so something like

```
config.MapRoute("DirectToHomeIndex", "{*uri}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
```